# Diagbox line does not appear on the pdf, and I get this error:

Tags: tables

This the main file :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside,openright,original]{report}

\input{Preambule}       
\input{CommandesPerso}  
\input{PageDeGarde}   

\author{S \scshape{B}}
%\title{ }
\title{ }
\specialite{}
\directeur{ \scshape{}}
\date{}
\juryi{Mme}{Professeur}{Président}
\jurya{Mme }{Professeur}{Examinateur}
\juryb{M}{Professeur}{Rapporteur}
\juryc{}{Professeur}{Rapporteur}
\juryd{}{Professeur}{Rapporteur}
\ecole{}

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfsubject={Manuscrit de thèse de doctorat},
    pdftitle={},
    pdfkeywords={}
}

\begin{document}

-*- mode: latex -*-

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagedegarde

%\cleardoublepage
    % Table des matières
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    % Pas besoin de trop détailler le sommaire ici (chapitres/sections)
        \dominitoc                      % Génération des mini-toc   \pagenumbering{arabic}
        
        \tableofcontents
            %\input{Dédicace} 
            \input{Remerciement}    
            %   \input{Résumé}
        \input{Abstract}
         \input{Glossaire}
    % Liste des figures
        \renewcommand*\listfigurename{Liste des figures}
        \listoffigures
    % Liste des tableaux
    \listoftables
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %\printglossaries
 \printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title={Liste des acronymes}, toctitle={Liste des acronymes}]     

\printglossary[title=Glossaire,toctitle=Glossaire]
        \printglossary[type=notation,title={Liste des symboles}, toctitle={Liste des symboles}]

    
        %\input{"Introduction générale"}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       
%        Contenu du document        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\bibliographystyle{Plain}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\setcounter{mtc}{3} % "Corrige" les minitocs décallés à cause des chapter* (ex : table des matières)
\pagenumbering{arabic}


%  \input{Introduction/Introduction générale}

\includefrom{Chapitre1/}{Chapitre1} 
\includefrom{Chapitre2/}{Chapitre2} 
  
%\input{"Conclusion générale"}
%\input{Ref}
%\renewcommand{\refname}{whatever}\contentsname{whatever}
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{{Références}}
\bibliography{Biblio}
%\printbibliography[title={Reference}]



% Annexes
\begin{appendix}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \includefrom{Annexes/}{Annexes}             % Figures en annexe
        \end{appendix}

\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
In chapitre2 file:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[!h]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1,8}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering \arraybackslash}c|c|c|}
     \hline
    %\diagbox{$ a $}{$ b $} & b & c & d \\
     \hline
    &&&\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \centering
    \caption{.}
    \label{Tab:2.5}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Preambule.tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[original]{pict2e} 

\usepackage{diagbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%% Faux texte, juste pour la démo
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{grffile}
%\usepackage[extendedchars]{grffile}
% \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}[2006/02/22]
 %\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  % \usepackage[encoding,filenameencoding=utf8]{grffile} 
 
%\grffilesetup{
%encoding,
%inputencoding=latin1,
%filenameencoding=utf8,
%} 
 
% \usepackage{selinput}
%  \SelectInputMappings{%
   %   agrave={à},
    %  eacute={é},
    %  Euro={€}
  %}
%% Réglage des fontes et typo    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    % LaTeX, comprend les accents !
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}      % Doit être chargé avant babel
%\usepackage{chapterbib}
%\usepackage[gather]{chapterbib}
%   \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{Références}}        % Met les références biblio dans un \section (au lieu de \section*)
        
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}                                     % Utilisation des fontes vectorielles modernes
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\usepackage{tocbibind}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Allure générale du document
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  % Place un FloatBarrier à chaque nouvelle section
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage[francais,nohints]{minitoc}      % Mini table des matières, en français
    \setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}    % Mini-toc détaillées (sections/sous-sections)
%\usepackage[notbib]{tocbibind}     % Ajoute les Tables des Matières/Figures/Tableaux à la table des matières

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Maths                         
\usepackage{amsmath}            % Permet de taper des formules mathématiques
\usepackage{amssymb}            % Permet d'utiliser des symboles mathématiques
\usepackage{amsfonts}           % Permet d'utiliser des polices mathématiques
\usepackage{nicefrac}           % Fractions 'inline'


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Tableaux
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{{\textsc{Tableau}}}}   % Renome 'table' en 'tableau'

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Eléments graphiques                    
\usepackage{graphicx, tipa}         % Permet l'inclusion d'images
\newcommand{\arc}[1]{{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%
  \ooalign{\resizebox{\wd9}{\height}{\texttoptiebar{\phantom{A}}}\cr#1}}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,automata}
    \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture={
        \shorthandoff{:;!?};}
    }}
    \pgfplotsset{every linear axis/.append style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={\,},
    }}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{import}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Mise en forme du texte        
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[load-configurations = abbreviations]{siunitx}
    \DeclareSIUnit{\MPa}{\mega\pascal}
    \DeclareSIUnit{\micron}{\micro\meter}
    \DeclareSIUnit{\tr}{tr}
    \DeclareSIPostPower\totheM{m}
    \sisetup{
    locale = FR,
      inter-unit-separator=$\cdot$,
      range-phrase=~\`{a}~,         % Utilise le tiret court pour dire "de... à"
      range-units=single,       % Cache l'unité sur la première borne
      }

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}  % Equations chimiques
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array, makecell, tabu}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Navigation dans le document
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfborder={0 0 0},
    colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        citecolor=red,
            pagebackref=true,
            ]{hyperref} % Créera automatiquement les liens internes au PDF
                    % Doit être chargé en dernier (Sauf exceptions ci-dessous)
            

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Packages qui doivent être chargés APRES hyperref              
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2.5cm,
            headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % Entête et pieds de page. Doit être placé APRES geometry
    \pagestyle{fancy}       % Indique que le style de la page sera justement fancy
    \lfoot[\thepage]{}      % gauche du pied de page
    \cfoot{}            % milieu du pied de page
    \rfoot[]{\thepage}      % droite du pied de page
    \fancyhead[RO, LE] {}   
    
    %\usepackage{glossaries}
    %\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
    %\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
%   \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,ucmark]{glossaries}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation} % Création d'un type de glossaire 'notation'
    \makeglossaries
    \loadglsentries{Glossaire}          % Utilisation d'un fichier externe pour la définition des entrées (Glossaire.tex)               

%\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\backmatter{
   % \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{%
       % \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}{%
       % \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}}%
   % \def\sectionmark##1{\relax}}
%\makeatother
```

I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.\diagbox@double@pict@NW ...box@setlinecolor \Line(0,\strip@pt \diagbox@ht )... \diagbox{$ a $}{$ b $} &`
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. I have not time now to dig further, but you have to write `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}` --- with a decimal point, not a comma.

Comment: Anyway, please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: With `\documentclass` etc. and `\usepackage{diagbox}` added and the `%` removed, it runs just file on my up-to-date LaTeX system. Is your system up-to-date? Did you have other packages that might interfere?

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the `original` option in the `\documentclass` and the `\usepackage[original]{pict2e}`. Leave these out and it probably works. You can even leave out the whole `\usepackage{pict2e}` because it is loaded by `diagbox`.

Comment: when I remove original option in the  \documentclass and the \usepackage[original]{pict2e} I get this error:

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Command \arc already defined.

Comment: You define `\arc` yourself in your Preamble. But it is also defined in `pict2e`. So use a different name for your own definition or use `\renewcommand{\arc}...` as you don't use the `\arc` from `pict2e`.